# When writing a makefile how can I kill a subprocess on exit?

Tags: makefile, background-process

Makefile:

```
default:
    command1 &
    command2 &
```

When I run `make` and hit <kbd>Control-C</kbd>, `command1` and `command2` continue running. How can I make it so that `command1` and `command2` are killed once make is killed? `command1` and `command2` should run in parallel. Command1 watches source files and compiles them. Command2 is a webserver.

Comment: It's going to be tricky.  The shell that launched the processes in background has exited, so the parent PID of the commands is going to be `1`, the `init` process (give or take — I'm using a few shorthands).  That means you'll need to know the PIDs of the commands, and there isn't an easy way to determine which instances of `command1` and `command2` belong to the current run of `make` — not reliably.  I think you need to rethink your whole approach, which gets us back to "what are you trying to do? — what are the background commands doing for you?".

Comment: If what you want to do is run `command1` and `command2` *in parallel*, with the option to abort them both, that's easy. If you want something else, then... I can't guess what it is.

Comment: @Beta I want parallel

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I want a compiler to watch by sources and to run a webserver. I am using make because Grunt and Gulp where way too complicated. I am running make by typing make and pressing enter in terminal. I other unrealated rules (tests, clean, etc...).

Comment: Put the information into the question — you can edit your own question most of the time (but don't change it so that existing answers are invalidated — in general).  So, you type `make` and it does the actions in the `default` rule — which runs two commands in the background — and then `make` immediately terminates.  You won't have time to type Control-C; you can't type fast enough. Either I'm an antiquated old fogey (a distinct possibility) or what you've said you're trying to do doesn't yet make sense. Do the commands leave PID files?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler make keeps running until I hit control-c; What is a PID file?

Comment: A PID file is a file created by a long running process, such as a web server, and contains its PID (process ID, process number).  The PID file is in a well-known location and allows you to discover which PID represents the currently running server (and allows you to check whether the server is running — if you have appropriate privileges). I'm surprised that `make` keeps running. Given the information in the question, none of the versions of `make` I've ever used would stick around. I'm glad you've managed to get an answer that suits you. I'm not sure this'll help others in the future, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use make's own parallelism option `make -j2` with a makefile like this :

```
default: task1 task2

task1:
        command1

task2:
        command2
```

make will take care of interrupting both command1 and command2.

Comment: Is there anyway I can make that happen when I run make with no arguments?

Comment: @user104317 The only ways I know of are setting the MAKEFLAGS environment variable, or using a shell alias, or a wrapper command, or even making make calls itself back with added options.

Comment: I found a solution that I like better. I don't full understand it but it works.

Comment: @user104317 Thank you for sharing

Comment: This doesn't work for all commands.  :(  In particular this one: `gcloud beta emulators datastore start`

Comment: @gaefan This only works for commands that block forver (i.e. never end). Could it be that you gcloud command returns to the shell after having started the process ?

Comment: Johan, `gcloud` doesn't terminate, but it does launch other processes in the background.  If you do `gcloud` from the command line and CTRL-C, then all the processes stop. But when you CTRL-C the running makefile, it doesn't stop all the processes started by `gcloud`.  It is probably a less common edge case for the otherwise good solution of your answer.

Comment: Actually I don't think using make for that is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works I have no idea why. I took it from https://veithen.github.io/2014/11/16/sigterm-propagation.html

`Makefile`:

```
.PHONY: default
default:
    bash build.sh
```

`build.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
trap 'kill -TERM $PID' TERM INT

webpack & # Command 1
http-server -p 8000 -c-1 & # Command 2

PID=$!
wait $PID
trap - TERM INT
wait $PID
EXIT_STATUS=$?
```

Comment: Why use Make at all?

Comment: @Beta because I plan on adding other tasks and I am tired of grunt/gulp